# htaccess pretty url to regular php file

Tags: .htaccess, web

I am trying to use my htaccess to allow me to send in a pretty url and have it route to a regular webpage.

So while I am sending in "http://www.foobar.com/dir1/file/id" I would like it to route to "http"//www.foobar.com/dir1/file.php?id=1" As I mentioned, I have been trying to achieve this through my htaccess file but I am just getting 404's all the time. I was hoping one of the gurus here can help me.

This is my htaccess on the dir1 directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^dir1/file/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ file.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This its working fine

```
//First Parameer
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ file.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ file.php?id=$1

//Second Parameter
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ users.php?user=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ users.php?user=$1&page=$2
```

Or try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# add trailing slash

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 

# rewrite gallery/ to gallery.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]

# redirect example.com/index.php to example.com/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

here you can change (tpl). file into your needs

and further

```
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```